# Insert data from a Repeater's textbox into a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am using a Repeater that has a label and textbox. It generates the correct labels based on columns in a table (First Name, Last Name, Address, etc). The user is meant to type in their information into the corresponding textbox.

After this, I need a way to insert their data from the textbox into my database. However what I am unsure of is exactly how to insert each item into the correct column of the database. I am using Stored Procedures, so it would be something like:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.Int).Value = firstName.Text;
```

Of course I cannot identify firstName.Text when the only textbox I have is a txtData repeated.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in RepeaterForm.Items)
                    {
                        Label lblData = rpItem.FindControl("lblData") as Label;
                        TextBox txtData = rpItem.FindControl("txtData") as TextBox;

                        if (txtData != null)
                        {
                            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            sqlCmd.CommandText = "spInsFormFields";
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            
                          //Code here
                           
                            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
       }
```

A sample repeater form could look like this:

> First Name: John
>
> Last Name: Smith
>
> Address: 123 Cherry Lane

And a sample of my database is like this:

> Registrant table
>
> FirstName, LastName, Address columns

Submit button should enter ONE row based on an `EventId` and `FormId` (which I collected earlier in my code)

**EDIT:**

Here is my Repeater code (as requested):

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterForm" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterForm_ItemCommand">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <table>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MyColumn") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                 <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     <br></br></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate><asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" /></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What is your exact issue? You have your SP which accepts all the parameters `First Name, Last Name, Address,` etc and in your SP probably you are inserting data to corresponding columns right?

Comment: Please show your repeater markup that would be more helpful in identifying your problem.

Comment: Well I'd like it to be smart enough to generate params and such on its own. This will be used for many custom forms that have many diff fields. For example, some forms will have an Address field while others won't.

Comment: @RockOn - But still you should have all those coulmns in a single physical table right?

Comment: I can add my code for you to see in the morning. (Currently on my phone without my code in front of me.) Thanks!

Comment: @Rahul Yes but users will be able to create custom columns/fields so it'll be very tedious for me to add each individual column as this is in production. I was thinking maybe there is a way to generate it differently but I'm not sure. (Perhaps take lblData's value and create params from this)

Comment: @RockOn - You can obviously create params but what about columns in table? If you are thinking of generating that too dynamically based on user input I would say better re-think your logic cz it's only going to complicate things.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I know,  it's kind of a complicated web app. It needs to be a form builder where admin are allowed to create custom fields for their forms. (However my question pertains to what an end user will be seeing - the form itself)

Comment: @Suprabhat Biswal I've added the Repeater code that you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepare your repeater like this:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="text"  name='<%#Eval("ColumnName") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>           
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And by using this C# code you can get all the values dynamicly :

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    List<Column> Columns = new List<Column>();
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Columns.Add(new Column { ColumnName = "ID" });
        Columns.Add(new Column { ColumnName = "Name" });
        Columns.Add(new Column { ColumnName = "Surname" });
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater1.DataSource = Columns;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> Values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in Columns)
        {
            Values.Add(item.ColumnName, Request.Form[item.ColumnName]);
        }
    }
}
class Column
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `txtFirstname`,`txtLastname`,`txtAddress` are the names for respective controls in the repeater, then You can access them by using following code:

```
 foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in RepeaterForm.Items)
            {
                TextBox tFirstname = rpItem.FindControl("txtFirstname") as TextBox;
                TextBox tLastname = rpItem.FindControl("txtLastname") as TextBox;
                TextBox tAddress = rpItem.FindControl("txtAddress") as TextBox;
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "spInsFormFields";
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
                if (tFirstname != null)
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tFirstname.Text;
                if (tLastname != null)
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tLastname.Text;
                if (tAddress != null)
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tAddress.Text;
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: what is your txtData??? when you give an answer, don't make mistakes in your code.

Comment: @ Khazratbek : That was by mistake; thanks for pointing that, I have updated the answer.